# Using SharedObject with complicated classes

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, shared-objects

I know that if I want to store a custom class with SharedObject, I have to use registerClassAlias.

```
registerClassAlias("MyClass", MyClass);
sharedObject.data.myObject = new MyClass();
```

But in my case, I have a custom class *whose fields are themselves instances of custom classes*. How can I store it in such a way as to recover the types when I load the data?

Specifically, the class in question is a `Graph` class which contains an array of Objects. This isn't the actual code, just an overview:

```
class Graph {
    public var vertices : Array;
}
```

I have an instance of this Graph class, and I'm filling its `vertices` field with instances of another class, called `Node`. I need to store this Graph instance in such a way that I can:

1. Recover it as a Graph instance.
2. Access the `vertices` field of this recovered instance, and then access the elements of that array as `Node` types.

I've tried throwing some `registerClassAlias("Node", Node)`'s in appropriate-seeming places, but it's not having any effect. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: it will work but you have to add serialisation methods so you can recover/store class state

Comment: It is [flash.utils.IExternalizable](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/utils/IExternalizable.html) that you have to use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With more complex data such as this, your best bet is to define `load()` and `save()` methods manually on objects that you want to store in a SharedObject. Those methods will define what data should be saved, simplified as much as possible, and collate it into a format of your choice such as JSON.

In this example, your `Graph` could have a method `save()` which looks like this:

```
public function save(name:String, sharedObject:SharedObject):void
{
    var list:Array = [];
    for each(var node:Node in vertices)
    {
        // Add a simple object defining the important Node properties
        // to the array we will save as JSON.
        list.push({ x: node.x, y: node.y });
    }

    sharedObject.data[name] = JSON.encode(list);
}
```

And then a `load()` function like so:

```
public function load(name:String, sharedObject:SharedObject):void
{
    // Empty current list of vertices.
    vertices = [];

    var list:Array = JSON.decode(sharedObject.data[name]);
    for each(var def:Object in list)
    {
        // Create real Node from simpler definition.
        var node:Node = new Node();

        node.x = def.x;
        node.y = def.y;
        vertices.push(node);
    }
}
```

Which would be utilized like:

```
existingGraph.save('myGraph', sharedObject);

var newGraph:Graph = new Graph();
newGraph.load('myGraph', sharedObject);
```

Comment: What exactly are the JSON.encode and JSON.decode methods? I can't find any reference to them in the [docs](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/JSON.html).

Comment: Actually, this won't work. I'm using flash CS5, which doesn't support the JSON API. Any way of doing this manually?

Comment: @JackM You can use the [as3corelib](https://github.com/mikechambers/as3corelib) for older versions of Flash Player. JSON is also just the data format I have used in my example - you can easily change it out for XML or even your own data format.

Comment: @JackM If that's the case you should probably write your own answer detailing what you did and accept that instead.

Comment: No, the important part of your answer was the suggestion to roll my own load/save code, and that's what I accepted.